# $A^{n}$ matrix problem without using $A=PDP^{-1}$ Eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrix-calculus

i have the following problem

Find $A^n$ for the following matrix

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I have tried the following, calculating for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$

\begin{equation}
A^1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad 
A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad 
A^3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 5 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \\
A^4=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 5 & 6\\
5 & 9 & 11 \\
6 & 11 & 14 
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad 
A^5=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 11 & 14\\
11 & 20 & 25 \\
14 & 25 & 31 
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad 
A^6=\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 25 & 31\\
25 & 45 & 56 \\
31 & 56 & 70
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

That gives the following terms

\begin{equation}
A_{11} = 0,1,1,3,6,14,...\\
A_{12} = 0,1,2,5,11,25,...\\
A_{22} = 1,2,4,9,20,45,...
\end{equation}

But i can't figure out the succesion in terms of n.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of Jordan normal form?

Comment: @richrow Since the matrix has 3 distinct eigenvalues, the Jordan normal form is exactly the Eigendecomposition the OP said he cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

With $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ as your base, check what happens when you operate on them
$$Ae_1 = e_3 \implies A^ne_1 = A^{n-1}e_3$$
$$Ae_2 = e_2+e_3 \implies A^ne_2 = A^{n-1}(e_2+e_3) = A^{n-1}e_3 + A^{n-1}e_2$$
$$Ae_3 = e_1+e_2+e_3\implies A^ne_3 = A^{n-1}(e_1+e_2+e_3) = $$
$$ = A^{n-1}e_1+A^{n-1}e_2+A^{n-1}e_3 = 2A^{n-2}e_3+A^{n-2}e_2 +A^{n-1}e_3$$
This implies a recursive expression for each of your columns, maybe it can be tweaked a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is using the eigenvalues in an implicit way.

$$A^3=2A^2+A-I_3$$

Which can be found by inspection or by calculating the characteristic polynomial.

Then, by long division
$$X^n=Q(X)(X^3-2X^2-X+1)+aX^2+bX+c$$
You can find $a,b,c$ by setting $X=\lambda_{1,2,3}$ the solutions to $X^3-2X^2-X+1$ in the above equation.

Then, setting $x=A$ in the equation we get:
$$A^n=aA^2+bA+C$$

**Note** The above implies that all entries of $A^n$ are of the form $c_1\lambda_1^n+c_2 \lambda_2^n+c_3 \lambda_3^n$ (which is consistent with diagonalisation). Since the roots
$\lambda_{1,2,3}$ of the equation
$$x^3-2x^2-x+1$$
are ugly, the formula is almost impossible to guess.